# Drop observations in panel data using Stata

Tags: stata

I have longitudinal data on individuals (id) surveyed in two years. Some individuals were not surveyed the second time. I would like to drop all outcomes on individuals surveyed only once so that I am left with a balanced data set.
How do I do this in Stata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do it for you:

```
by id, sort: drop if _N!=2
```

The `by id` will execute the command following the colon separately for each value of `id`, and `_N` will be the number of observations with that `id`.