# drop section of panel data in Stata

Tags: stata

I think that my question is similar to this one: [Drop observations in panel data using Stata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36926272/drop-observations-in-panel-data-using-stata)
but I am still doing something wrong and it isn't quite working for me.

I have panel data with the following variables:
`Year` - `Month` - `Subject` - `Trial` - `Attempt` - `Reward`

Each subject has 4 trials (or rounds), with 5 attempts per round. The reward changes by attempt and round, the 5th (last) attempt is ALWAYS = 2. For each subject, one of the 4 trials was randomly chosen to have all 5 attempts have `reward = 2` (normally attempts 1-4 have `reward = 1`). I need to delete those "bonus trials".

I know that I need to use `by` (http://www.stata.com/manuals13/dby.pdf), but I seem to be doing it incorrectly.  If I do this:

```
by trial: drop if attempt == 2 & reward == 2
```

then I get

> not sorted.

If I do this:

```
by trial, sort: drop if attempt == 2 & reward == 2
```

it drops 1 observation, when I need it to drop all 5 observations in that trial.

data example:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input int Year str3 Month byte(Subject Trial Attempt Reward) str1 Todrop
2016 "Feb" 1 1 1 1 "" 
2016 "Feb" 1 1 2 1 "" 
2016 "Feb" 1 1 3 1 "" 
2016 "Feb" 1 1 4 1 "" 
2016 "Feb" 1 1 5 2 "" 
2016 "Feb" 1 2 1 1 "" 
2016 "Feb" 1 2 2 1 "" 
2016 "Feb" 1 2 3 1 "" 
2016 "Feb" 1 2 4 1 "" 
2016 "Feb" 1 2 5 2 "" 
2016 "Feb" 1 3 1 2 "*"
2016 "Feb" 1 3 2 2 "*"
2016 "Feb" 1 3 3 2 "*"
2016 "Feb" 1 3 4 2 "*"
2016 "Feb" 1 3 5 2 "*"
2016 "Feb" 2 1 1 1 "" 
2016 "Feb" 2 1 2 1 "" 
2016 "Feb" 2 1 3 1 "" 
2016 "Feb" 2 1 4 1 "" 
2016 "Feb" 2 1 5 2 "" 
2016 "Feb" 2 2 1 2 "*"
2016 "Feb" 2 2 2 2 "*"
2016 "Feb" 2 2 3 2 "*"
2016 "Feb" 2 2 4 2 "*"
2016 "Feb" 2 2 5 2 "*"
2016 "Feb" 2 3 1 1 "" 
2016 "Feb" 2 3 2 1 "" 
2016 "Feb" 2 3 3 1 "" 
2016 "Feb" 2 3 4 1 "" 
2016 "Feb" 2 3 5 2 "" 
end
```

Above is an example for two subjects. What I would like to be able to do is to drop all of trial 3 for subject 1, and all of trial 2 for subject 2 (the starred trials) but not to drop the others (non-starred trials). That is, the variable `Todrop` is `*` for observations to be `drop`ped and empty otherwise.

Comment: I have suggested some edits to, in large part, improve the question's formatting.  However, without sample data and a reproducible example you may find it difficult to get an answer. If it helps, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: hey amie please look at my answer. if that works, please accept. thanks

Comment: I've edited your data example so that it can copied and pasted directly into Stata as `input` code. See `dataex` (SSC) for the means to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming data are read in as in your example, you can identify which observations to `drop` by

```
 bysort Year Month Subject Trial (Reward) : gen todrop = Reward[1] == 2 & Reward[5] == 2
```

The principles are:

1. Define groups by cross-combinations of variables. As you say, `by:` gives a framework here.
2. Every value of `Reward` must be 2 in groups to be `drop`ped. If so, then it's necessary and sufficient that after `sort`ing on `Reward` within groups, the first and the last value be both 2.

Verify that `todrop` as defined above is 1 if and only if `Todrop` is `*`. (e.g. look at a `tabulate *drop, missing`).

Once satisfied,

```
drop if todrop
```

Much more at [this Stata FAQ](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/listing-observations-in-group/),

Comment: Thank you for all your help with this.

Comment: Accepting an answer would boost your reputation (and mine, I should admit)!

Comment: Thank you for all your help with this, I finally have something working!
Strangely, it did not work until I dropped the parenthesis from Reward, so bysort Year Month Subject Trial Reward : gen todrop = Reward[1] == 2 & Reward[5] == 2 did the trick. Any idea why that would happen? From everything you said and what I have read about by that seems like it should not happen.

Comment: What's strange is the assertion that you need to drop the parentheses because they are an **essential** part of the solution! You shouldn't accept my answer if you think it's wrong, but I don't believe it is. The code reproduces what is stated as desired in your example.  What the parentheses do is documented in every serious discussion of `by:` starting with the `help` and the manual entry.

Answer (score 0):

```
gen flag_temp=1 if attempt == 2 & reward == 2
bysort trial: egen flag=min(flag_temp)

drop if flag==1
```

**boom**

Comment: Ok that was close, but the "bonus round" trial is random, and not the same for different participants. So for participant A and C, the bonus round was trial 2, but for participant B the bonus round was trial 3- So I would want only trial 2 dropped for A and C, and only trial 3 for B. This code deletes both trial 2 and trial 3 for all three participants.

Comment: Amie: Please give a data example. This is all clear to you but asking people to hold all the rules in their heads without an example is harder. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for how to ask a good question.