# Panel data - drop observations in stata

Tags: stata

I have panel data containing 4 waves. I need help tp keep only individuals who have participated in all waves. I saw this post [drop observations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36926272/drop-observations-in-panel-data-using-stata?noredirect=1&lq=1), but ending deleting everything.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The details depend on details you haven't given. But for example suppose you have variables `id` and `wave` where `wave` runs 1 2 3 4. Conditions for selecting complete panels only might be

```
bysort id : keep if _N == 4
```

or

```
egen total = total(wave), by(id) 
keep if total == 10
```

These commands won't help if you have a `wave` variable always present but the problem is missing values on other variables.

Comment: Thanks Nick! I have also education, which is missig mostly in wave 4. So I have data on some individuals that are complete, but some only shows wave 1, 2 and 3. How do I delete all IDs who have missing in education?

Comment: You need to count non-missings in each observation using an `egen` row function. Then check that you have 4 complete observations for each identifier.  Your question would get more attention with a small but realistic data example. See the Stata tag wiki for details.

Comment: Thanks again. The code works! :)